# Esta sintaxis es valida en jquery?

Tags: javascript, datatables, jquery-validate

Tengo este codigo, por lo que se en javascript deberia haver un return true y return false,pero en esta sentencia solo hay un return false, el return true esta implicito?

if (_form.find('#name').val()==='') {
            _form.find('#name').addClass('u-validate');
            return false;
        };

esta es la funcion original

```js
 $("#btn-registrar").on('click',  function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var _form = $("#form-add-marcas");

  if (_form.find('#name').val()==='') {
   _form.find('#name').addClass('u-validate');
   return false;
  };

  if (_form.find('#description').val()==='') {
   _form.find('#description').addClass('u-validate');
   return false;
  };


  $.ajax({
   url: baseURL +'marcas/action_add',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: _form.serializeArray(),
  })
  .done(function(response) {
   
   if (Boolean(response.status)===true) {
    loadURL(baseURL+'marcas/list_marcas');

    //alert(response.message);
   }else{
    alert(response.message);
    _form.find('#'+response.id).addClass('u-validate');
   }
  })
  .fail(function(response) {
   console.log("error",response);
  })
   
 });
```

Comment: Por lo que veo nunca devolverá un true. Lo único que hace ese if es agregar una clase y retornar false. El return true debe estar en otra parte pero aquí no lo veo.

Comment: ok...en ese caso  el return false a que se debe,es decir por que lo ponen false y no true?

Comment: Ese if debe estar dentro de una función que retorna un valor booleano el return false lo que hace es devolver eso como salida de la función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, amigo ya ahora si puedo responderte te explico lo que hace tu javascript, cuando le das **click** al botón estas generando un evento **OnClick**, lo que hacen esos **if** es que si consiguen que los campos **name** y **description** están vacíos te retorna un false en la función y te cancela el evento **OnClick**. Se podría decir que al hacer click al botón estas enviando un true Click = True y al retornar el false cancelas eso Click = False.

```js
$("#btn-registrar").on('click',  function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var _form = $("#form-add-marcas");
  
  if (_form.find('#name').val()==='') {
    _form.find('#name').addClass('u-validate');
    return false; //CANCELAR EL CLICK
  };
  
  if (_form.find('#description').val()==='') {
    _form.find('#description').addClass('u-validate');
    return false; //CANCELAR EL CLICK
  };
  
  $.ajax({
    url: baseURL +'marcas/action_add',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: _form.serializeArray(),
  })
  .done(function(response) {
   
    if (Boolean(response.status)===true) {
      loadURL(baseURL+'marcas/list_marcas');
      //alert(response.message);
    }else{
      alert(response.message);
      _form.find('#'+response.id).addClass('u-validate');
    }
  })
  .fail(function(response) {
    console.log("error",response);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin ver el `HTML` es un poco especulación, pero... si suponemos que el botón está dentro de un `FORM` al hacer click lo esperado es que se envíe el `FORM`.

La primera instrucción `event.preventDefault();` (para este evento prevenir la acción default) evita este comportamiento, luego las condiciones que retornan `false` cancelan el click (el `FORM` no se envía) y la función termina ahí.

Mas adelante hay una llamada ajax que envía la información del `FORM`, así que a partir de ese punto no haría falta retornar `true`, de lo contrario se estaría reenviando el `FORM`: una vez por ajax la segunda vez por el `HTML`.